# Cannot import my custom components in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, module, components

I am quite new to Angular and have a problem importing my components.
I declaired a module where I get all the components in, to use it as a shared components module
I use input component inside sidebar component, and sidebar component on the app module, works fine.
The problem is when I want to use input component inside base page, I import the module and use the tag on the html side and visual studio code doesn't warn me anything, but when compiling, console tells me that `'app-input' is not a known element`

In my project I have the following structure

```
App
|-pages
|--base
|
|-widgets
|--sidebar
|---sidebar.component.ts
|--input
|---input.component.ts
|--widgets.module.ts
|
|-app.module.ts
```

input.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-input',
  templateUrl: './input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input.component.css']
})
export class InputComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

widgets.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';
import { SidebarComponent } from './sidebar/sidebar.component';
import { InputComponent } from './input/input.component';



@NgModule({
  declarations:[
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    SidebarComponent,
    InputComponent
  ],
  exports:[
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    SidebarComponent,
    InputComponent
  ]
})
export class WidgetsModule { }
```

I coudn't find any solution on the internet (or coudn't figure out what's going on for sure) and I have been looking to solve it for a week. I look forward for your answers and thanks in advance

**EDIT 1**

base.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { BaseRoutingModule } from './base-routing.module';
import { BaseComponent } from './base.component';
import { WidgetsModule } from 'src/app/widgets/widgets.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    BaseComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BaseRoutingModule,
    WidgetsModule
  ]
})
export class BaseModule { }
```

**EDIT 2**

Correct the folder structure

Comment: Since you have WidgetsModule imported and InputComponent is exported inside it, there doesn't seem to be a reason why this wouldn't work. One thing to point out, if your Input component has a module, import that module inside the Widgets module (and then export it as well). And double check if your component selector for the Input component is in fact `app-input`, otherwise I see no reason why this shouldn't work.

Comment: I think I am on the correct way, but it is still not working. I leave here the repository just in case T.T

Comment: Forgot to mention - If you're importing the Input Module, inside it, you have to export your Input component as well.

Comment: the input component belongs to WidgetsModule, if I undertood you well, this is what you are telling me to do, right?

Comment: Uhm, looking at your file structure, I saw that you have an Input Module, so that's why I suggested that you add the Input Module to your Widgets Module's imports and exports (as opposed to adding the component itself to the declarations) and then whenever you import Widgets Module you should have access to the Input Component. However for this you will need to add the Input Component inside the exports of the Input Module. Also, if you do this, it allows you to only import the Input Module if you want to reuse only the Input Component in multiple other components.

Comment: sorry, I wrote it bad, I've correct the file structure. It has to be read as "sidebar.component.ts and input.component.ts, in other hand I forgot to add the repository https://github.com/MatiasGabrielTommasi/ClientApp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing your repository, I found out that your issue is that you've not imported the `BaseModule` inside your `AppModule`. Otherwise your logic was correct.

Comment: thanks for your help justchecking, I imported as you mentioned and everything went well, but why do I need to import the pages to the app.module then? is it that I need to add everything I have on the site to the app.module to get it working? (again, thanks!)

Comment: Good question, it's a bit of a prolonged topic, so I separated two good articles where you can get a good understanding on this - https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/understanding-the-angular-root-app-module . Also this one - https://angular.io/guide/feature-modules. I suggest reading the second article first. But to answer your question briefly - with your current approach, yes, you have to let the app module know about your feature modules, so they can have  access to each other. Now in a lazy loaded approach, that wouldn't be the case (i.e. explained a bit in the first link).

Answer (score 0):

This error is usually occures when you did not import the module, where you want to use that component. So the module which has the base page component should import the WidgetsModule.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Zsombor, I've edit the post adding the basepage's code. I think the import is ok, and visual studio dowsn't warn me about anything, and it allows me to use the html tag (<app-input>) inside the base page html